# Efficiently returning 1-9 bytes from a function

Tags: rust, iterator

There are at least three ways to return bytes from a function.

- As an iterator producing `u8`s.
- Taking a `Writer` as an argument.
- Taking an `&mut [u8]` argument.

My function will be producing 1-9 bytes on each call.

I want it to be easily useable, and efficient, to:

- Feed an iterator pipeline which consumes bytes.
- Write to disk.
- Write to network.
- Write to memory.

Can I just implement the function once, and trust the the compiler will make a single implementation efficient for all use cases, when the user adapts the output?

Or do I need to implement it three (or more) times to cover all the use-cases efficiently?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is going to be "benchmark all the approaches under your particular workload and see which one is faster."

Comment: `&mut [u8]` implements `Write`, so a function taking a `T: Write` will work fine and *should* be as efficient as a direct `&mut [u8]` implementation once the compiler has had its way with it. But the only way to be sure is to actually implement it and compare the compiler outputs & benchmark results.

Comment: I don't think you can trivially bridge between `Write` and `Iterator` though, as one is push-processed while the other one is pull-processed. There might be cases where you can bridge the two e.g. by lying through `WouldBlock` (eventually `StorageFull`) then bridging over; or cross-thread communication.

Comment: @Masklinn What do other people do?  Do they produce a pull and push implementation for each encoding algorithm?

Comment: @fadedbee couldn't tell you. maybe take a gander at the most common crates and see? I'd expect most to pick one or the other depending on their primary use case / usage pattern e.g. I think it'd be rather odd (and indefficient, and constraining) for a compressor or an encoder to yield an `Iterator<u8>`, I'd usually expect a `Write` to be involved even when not ideal for all cases.

Comment: The convenience of the `Write` case would also depend on the source being able to suspend and resume, the writer having to write everything in one shot would obviously be more constraining than if it were possible to invoke it multiple times, and run code inbetween (this would also make a bridging iterator somewhat feasible, though possibly a tad variable / inconsistent in latency).

Comment: You can always write a new `trait Take1to9Bytes { fn take_bytes(&mut self, bs: &[u8]); }`, and write a couple of blanket impls for `T: Write` and so on. If an user has a particular use case they can implement your trait optimally instead of adapting `Write` or `Iterator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's evaluate the options.

If we write a function that takes `&mut [u8]`, and we want to use it:

- To write to disk/network (both are `std::io::Write`) - we can create an array of type `[u8; 9]` (since it writes up to 9 bytes), pass it to it, and then pass it (more precisely, the part of it that was actually written to) to [`Write::write_all()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_all).
- Writing to the memory is easiest: just pass a slice to an array of size `[u8; 9]`.
- If we want to feed it into an iterator pipeline, we will need to have a little boilerplate:

```rust
let bytes = [0; 9];
let written = foo(&mut bytes);
bytes.into_iter().take(written).some_iterator_chain()
// Or
bytes[..written].iter().copied().some_iterator_chain()
```

But the compiler will probably optimize both ways to a very efficient assembly.

If we'll write an iterator that takes `std::io::Write`, it'll be very easy to write to the disk/network, and we will even be able to write to the memory using [the implementation of `Write` for `&mut [u8]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#impl-Write-6), but piping it through iterators will require the same boilerplate as above. Overall, it pretty much doesn't matter whether you choose to write to `&mut [u8]` or to a type implementing `Write`.

However, if we return an iterator, we can easily put it in an iterator chain, write to memory is also easy using a `for` loop, but to write to network/disk, you will have either to call `write()` (or `write_all()`) mutliple times, which is usually less efficient than once, or collect it into a `Vec`, which is also less efficient. So this is probably the worse option.